# R, Code works without for loop, but not inside loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, rstudio

I want to replace entries of one column (Fraction) of a certain dataframe (driftm, 4 columns, 69042 rows) with a value found in another dataframe (results, 40 rows).

My idea was as follows:

```
driftm$Fraction[i] <-
as.vector((results$Fraction[match((driftm$variable[i]), (results$WorkingCode))]))
```

The variable I check (drift$variable) is a factor, thus I convert to a vector. When manually setting i to any value within the length of driftm$value, the code works and replaces accordingly. But in a for loop it does nothing.

```
for (i in length(driftm$values)){
driftm$Fraction[i] <-
as.vector((results$Fraction[match((driftm$variable[i]), (results$WorkingCode))]))
}
```

[This is the dataframe driftm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUe0b.png)
[This is the dataframe results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKHjT.png)

So basically I want to replace, what is now written as "Replace" with the correct string for said Fraction, traken from results$Fraction.

What could be a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Needs more `as.character` probably...

Comment: Yeah it is not very elegant xD Changed it, still doesn't work

Comment: So, just so I understand, there are 40 rows in your main df `driftm`, which you want to replace by what's in results? Can you create an index of the rows in `driftm` that you would like to replace and use that instead of this solution?
It would be helpful if you gave us a sample of data (a few rows you want to replace, a few that you don't, and a few from results).

Comment: Using for loop is not an elegant way of doing this. But putting this aside, we need some sample data so we can verify the error and troubleshoot it.

Comment: No there are 40 rows in results. Results is used in the match() function, where I want to find the same entry I have in driftm$Fraction. 
There are 69042 rows in driftm$fraction, but the values therein are only in the space of the values found in results.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue

Despite still being interested in a more elegant solution, my simple mistake was the definition of the for loop.

```
for (i in **1:**length(driftm$variable){
driftm$Fraction[i] <-
as.vector((results$Fraction[match((driftm$variable[i]), (results$WorkingCode))]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more elegant solution:

Data:

```
driftm<-data.frame(Fraction=1:10, Variable=c(letters[1:5],letters[5:1]))
results<-data.frame(Fraction=10:11, WorkingCode=c(letters[2:3]))
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
driftm$Fraction<-left_join(driftm,results,by=c("Variable"="WorkingCode")) %>% 
  with(coalesce(Fraction.y,Fraction.x))
```

Result:

```
   Fraction Variable
1         1        a
2        10        b
3        11        c
4         4        d
5         5        e
6         6        e
7         7        d
8        11        c
9        10        b
10       10        a
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The join function in dplyr looks like a fantastic way of doing it. Less straight forward but maybe faster?

Comment: Should be significantly faster. I modified the code to be slightly more straightforward, using `coalesce`.